Troubles filtering my source from EveryAngle (Angles for SAP) using Odata in PowerQuery
I'm having troubles filtering my data uploaded from everyangle through Odata in Powerquery,
The "$select" option does work, but the "$filter" doesn't.
I've tried many things I've seen on blogs, unsuccessfully...
here is my source specification :
OData.Feed("https://everyangle.corp.XXXXX/odata/PEC_100/odata/T_DQ_MFG_CORE_Follow_up_of_ZCOM__ZLOG__ZLG_order_due_A__Current_delivery_deadlines__Remaining_to_be_delivered__L1_4370_28063?$filter=SalesOrder__VBAK_AUART eq 'ZLOG'", null, [Implementation="2.0"]).
I want to filter a specific type of sales orders category .
It returns the full dataset, unfilter, without apparent errors.
It is necessary for me to filter from the source as the dataset uploaded is very large otherwise (resulting ultimately in very long updating of my powerBI).
Thank you in advance,
(Please use a simple language, I'm not a code master :'))
